# How to run a vue computed property only once?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a computed property that populates an array, however i'm working with this array afterwards (pushing from & to it) and i want once the array is empty, to remain empty (said computed property not to populate it again).How can i do that? I'm using a computed property because i'm fetching data from the Vuex store via getter.
Here's the property in question:

```
populateAvailableMachines() {
  Object.values(this.userData).forEach(user => {
    if (this.$auth.user().id == user.id) {
      if (this.availableMachines.length == 0) {
        Object.keys(user.machine).forEach(key => {
          this.availableMachines.push(user.machine[key].machine_name);
        });
      }
    }
  });
},
```

And here's the method that pushes/splices:

```
addMachineTab(item) {
  let index = this.availableMachines.indexOf(item);
  this.selectedMachines.push(this.availableMachines.splice(index, 1));
},
```

What i want to achieve is, once all the values from the available machines array are moved to the selected machines array, not to re-run the computed property that populates the empty available machines array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use watcher instead.

```
watch: {
  userData: {
    handler: function (val, oldVal) {
      if(this.availableMachines.length > 0){
        // put your populate logic here
      }
    },
    deep: true
  }
},
```

Besides, you may need to initialize your data(`userData` and `availableMachines`) in `created` or `mounted` hook.

Answer (score 5):

It' not recommended to make `computed` properties produce any side effects like `data` mutating.
It would better to move `populateAvailableMachines` function to methods and call it only once (e.g. on mounted).

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for your feedback! I've already tried that, but when i move the computed property to methods, `this.userData` was an empty object (not populated with the actual values i need). In order to populate it, i run an action on another page.
Also, i dont think i produce any `data` mutations, i just set an array in my component to a getter's data.

Comment: You mutates data by doing `this.availableMachines.push`. Why don't you want to run `populateAvailableMachines` as a method right after you save your fetch results to `this.userData`?